# How to use square brackets within an exec command in Tcl/expect (Linux)

Tags: tcl, exec, expect, square-bracket

I have searched the web (including StackOverflow) for an hour now and can't seem to figure this simple thing out. I'm writing an expect script for some automation solution, and it's something quite small (automating the creation of encrypted Truecrypt volumes, feeding entropy data from /dev/urandom into Truecrypt using expect/Tcl, because this only works interactively).

My main problem is: How do I run the Tcl exec command to launch a system command including square brackets, and then feed the output to a variable? Like this:

```
set entropyfeed [exec tr -dc [:graph:] < /dev/urandom | head -c 320]
```

So this is supposed to read pseudorandom data from /dev/urandom, then filter out all the non-printable characters ("[:graph:]" only!) using tr and return the first 320 printable chars into the variable $entropyfeed. This works with any other command that does not use arguments with square brackets!

Tcl seems to always interpret [] as a kind of backticks, trying to run what's inside as a Tcl command. I was unable to find a way to escape the brackets in that exec call properly and have this run like I want, no matter whether I tried \[:graph:\] or {[:graph:]} or multiple backslashes or whatever. I'd really like to use [:graph:] instead of some pattern like a-zA-Z0-9. Plus, I now really wanna now how to do this right!

```
set entropyfeed [exec tr -dc \[:graph:\] < /dev/urandom | head -c 320]
```

This isn't right...

```
set entropyfeed [exec tr -dc {[:graph:]} < /dev/urandom | head -c 320]
```

...and this isn't either.

```
set entropyfeed [exec tr -dc \\[:graph:\\] < /dev/urandom | head -c 320]
```

Nope.

```
set entropyfeed [exec tr -dc \\\[:graph:\\\] < /dev/urandom | head -c 320]
```

Na-ah. So just desperately drowning that line in backslashes isn't going to help...

In the `{[:graph:]}` and `\\[:graph:\\]` cases it would actually print the characters I need on screen (almost a success?) but then die with the error "child killed: write on pipe with no readers". This doesn't happen when I run the original command on a Bash. It seems as if the data's been misdirected somehow in this case, but I'm just at a loss here.

Any insights into how this is done properly in Tcl/expect are much appreciated, I have zero experience in this language!

Comment: I have just figured out the "write on pipe with no readers" issue. It seems that `head -c 320` shall not terminate with `tr -dc [:graph:] < /dev/urandom` still feeding data to it, into a broken pipe at this point. This causes a SIGPIPE signal killing the process.

But why does this not happen on any interactive shell like sh or Bash? Maybe some buffer issue or something? So it seems `{[:graph:]}` and `\\[:graph:\\]` are actually correct, but the pipe is breaking. In newer versions of Tcl, exec has an option "-noPipeError" for this, but my Tcl version on CentOS 6.5 Linux seems to be too old..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's annoying. Since a shell doesn't seem bothered by it, you could do this:

```
set entropyfeed [exec sh -c {tr -dc '[:graph:]' < /dev/urandom | head -c 320}]
```

Or if you just want a random string of printable ascii chars:

```
proc random_string {n} {
    for {set i 1} {$i <= $n} {incr i} {
        append data [format %c [expr {33+int(94*rand())}]]
    }
    return $data
}
set entropyfeed [random_string 320]
```

Comment: Ha, awesome. And so simple. Just spawn a shell instead.. Oh man. This also solves the breaking pipe issue! I guess your second solution is more elegant though as it does not rely on platform-dependent binaries, just purely calling Tcls own functions like rand().

In any case, both work, thank you very much!

Comment: And NOW I just got how you limited the range of characters to printable ones by creating the proper integer numbers for the 7-Bit ASCII table. Beautiful. Today I really learned something!

Answer (score 1):

This would be the right one:

```
set entropyfeed [exec tr -dc {[:graph:]} < /dev/urandom | head -c 320]
```

Except that the early close of the output pipe (because that's how `head` works) causes `tr` to exit due to a signal, and `exec` picks that up and generates an error. The `exec` command is sometimes *very* annoying.

It might be easiest to just use Tcl to do all the work directly:

```
set entropyfeed ""
set f [open /dev/urandom rb]
# Older versions of Tcl need:
#    set f [open /dev/urandom]
#    fconfigure $f -translation binary
while {[string length $entropyfeed] < 320} {
    set c [read $f 1]
    if {[string is graph $c]} {
        append entropyfeed $c
    }
}
close $f
```

That should be pretty much identical, except now it only relies on the system device and not external programs. (You could use Tcl's built-in RNG instead, but we don't make any kind of guarantees on how good that is. Other than that it's thread-local — or rather it's interpreter-local — so there's no nasty surprises in there.)

Comment: Interesting, just not fully cross-platform (not that I would've asked for that). Usually, I should care a lot about security here, because creating entropy data for encrypted volumes needs to be done right! It's just that in my case it's a low-risk test run for a version of Truecrypt whose code I have modified a bit, so the source of randomness doesn't have to be perfect (thus /dev/urandom and not the slow /dev/random in my first attempt). But interesting to see yet another solution for creating printable chars in slightly more easily understandable code. Thanks! (Tcl is really weird for me..)